# Multiple simultaneous queries into same table

Tags: c#, sql, t-sql, asynchronous

We have an Export feature in our app that reads the whole DB, transforms it into JSON and compresses everything into a neat ZIP file. The whole thing works pretty fast, except for the queries, which take minutes to finish since some of the tables have 100K+ rows and sometimes 80+ columns.

I thought, then, that I could paginate these huge tables every 1000 rows (chunkSize) and run a number of simultaneous queries (numberOfTasks) to fetch their content.

```
        var dataList = new List<dynamic>();
        var tasks = new List<Task>();

        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfTasks; i++)
        {
            var min = (i * chunkSize) + 1;
            var max = (i + 1) * chunkSize;
            var sql =$@"SELECT *
                        FROM(
                            SELECT
                                ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY {firstColumn}) AS RowNum,
                                *
                            FROM {currentTable}
                            ) AS RowConstrainedResult
                        WHERE RowNum >= {min}
                            AND RowNum < {max}
                        ORDER BY RowNum";

            tasks.Add(
                Task.Run(() =>
                {
                    AppendItensToDataList(conn, listagem, sql);
                })
            );
        };

        await Task.WhenAll(tasks);

        return dataList;
```

But the performance here is abysmal: it actually fails to deliver the content, whereas the sync version of this code does sometimes manage to do it, albeit with the risk of timeout.
What am I doing wrong? Is asynchronous programming useless when it comes to reading data from the disk?

I'll appreciate any recommendations for further reading.

Comment: You aren't doing it asynchronously but concurrently. `AppendItensToDataList` looks like synchronous method which is running on a separate thread. Btw, there's almost no sense to fetch the data concurrently from the same DB table.

Comment: Hmm, that _is_ true, thanks for pointing it out! Could you elaborate a little on your reply? What other way could we try to optimize the reading of a massive table if not with concurrent queries?

Comment: Just load not more data than needed.

Comment: Everything has to be loaded, unfortunately. Are concurrent queries on different tables anyhow effective?

Comment: Depends on DB type and connection setup. On well optimized table single query must be always faster than multiple partitioned ones, for the same amount of rows.

Comment: The _actual execution plan_ may give you some idea of whether there is a bottleneck in the database other than the size of the data being exported. You can add the plan to your question, if appropriate, using [paste the plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/instructions/).

Comment: Why reinvent the wheel, just use `Backup`/`Restore` or maybe bacpac